# I'm having issue when i run my java application on a Sco OpenServer Release 5.0.6

Tags: java, unix

My Sco OpenServer Release 5.0.6 have a java version which is :

# java -version

**java version "1.3.1_22"**

Java(Tm) Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build SCO-UNIX-J2SE-1.3.1_22:*
FCS*:20080305)
Classic VM (build SCO-UNIX-J2SE-1.3.1_22:*FCS*:20080305, green threads, sunwjit)

My java application have developed in **Windows** with java version 6 update 25.

i understand , i should change my code to work with java 1.3 like following trouble :

1. **Generic** is not supported like `ArrayList<String>`
2. **String.format** is not supported for `(String,double)`
3. **For each loop** is not supported

What code should come to replace the unsupported java version code below?

```
ArrayList<String> messages;

for (String message : messages)

String.format("%1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY %1$tI:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp", new Date())
```

Comment: You could upgrade to [Java 1.4.2 on OpenServer 5.0.7](http://www.sco.com/support/update/download/release.php?rid=377). But you'll still not get support for generics, unless you move to OpenServer 6, which appears to have Java 5 (not 6). You might also want to consider developing on the same JRE as the one you intend to deploy on; the APIs have changed since Java 1.3.

Comment: @VineetReynolds : My Sco OpenServer stay safe with release 5.0.6 as a application server and i don't a permission to ask server administrator to update the **OS** . But i have to developer the java application to run on the server and then my project will be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there no possibility to upgrade the version of Java on your server? 1.3 is pretty ancient and I think you'll end up with trouble. But to answer your specific questions:

```
   /* ArrayList<String> messages; */
   ArrayList messages;

   /* for (String message : messages) */
   for (Iterator it = messages.iterator(); ; it.hasNext()) {
       String message = it.next();
       ...
   }

   /* String.format("%1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY %1$tI:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp", new Date()) */
   new SimpleDateFormat("your-desired-format").format(new Date());
```

Comment: I'm looking at your written code , i think it's a bit confusing. To sum up :
 - i should use **iterator** instead of **For each loop** , right?

Comment: In Java 3 there's no for-each, so you need to do use an iterator, or use a "for (int i =0; i <...." - but I prefer iterators because they work on anything that is iterable.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<messages.size();i++) {
     String s = messages.get(i).toString();
}
```

Comment: i've already done that but i hope you can help me about `Generic` and `String.format`.